# HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed while calling web api delete method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call from MVC controller application to WEBAPI applicaiton method. I am getting error 405 method not allowed. Its working fine while calling GET and POST.

MVC Applicaiton:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteService(int id) {
        //code for webapi
    }
```

WEB API application:

```
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteService(int id) {
        try {
            ServicesModel service = dbContext.Services.Find(id);
            IEnumerable<ServicePropertiesModel> serviceProperies = dbContext.ServiceProperties.Where(x => x.ServiceId == id);
            if (service != null) {

                foreach (ServicePropertiesModel s in serviceProperies) {
                    dbContext.ServiceProperties.Remove(s);
                }
                dbContext.Services.Remove(service);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        } catch {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Thnaking you.
  Regards,Sekhar

Comment: Are you facing this issue on your local machine?

Comment: Why is the delete marked as static?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the WebAPI? Why is the WebApi method static?

Comment: I am changed my code. please find the code for more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the section where you are calling the service?

Comment: If you are using HttpClient to request web api then use DeleteAsync instead of any other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The methods PUT and DELETE are not allowed by default. You have to allow them in your web applications web.config.